# MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::current() returns nothing but it should

Tags: php, mongodb, php-8

I'm on PHP 8.

`var_dump(get_class($usernameInDb));` returns `string(21) "MongoDB\Driver\Cursor"`

`var_dump($usernameInDb);` shows that there is a document.

`$avirer = $usernameInDb->current();` doesn't cause a PHP error in error.log.

`var_dump($avirer);` returns `int(8) string(26) "Undefined variable: avirer"`

It seems to me in contradiction with [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php)

Does someone know what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fixed [bug](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/1183).

`$avirer` is undefined because `$usernameInDb->current()` did not handle invalid positions that caused the `$avirer` to be in an invalid state.

If you do something like

```
var_dump($cursor->current());
echo gettype($cursor->current());
```

The output will be

```
UNKNOWN:0
unknown type
```

Which is how [var_dump](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/77f172725a37c8ddee750bf6970529a1570fbc86/ext/standard/var.c#L202) and [gettype](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1b4fd5825a820873e4ed0f326bcb890e660dc39c/ext/standard/type.c#L85) handle `Unknown` data types.